# Powershell script that checks if a file is X Days old and alert me via email

Tags: powershell

I have the below script and it works, i want it to be able to send me an email if my file is 2 days old. I'm not sure how to get the email part working.
Thank you

```
$fullPath = "\\test\avvscan.dat"
$numdays = 2
$numhours = 1
$nummins = 1
function ShowOldFiles($path, $days, $hours, $mins)
{
    $files = @(get-childitem $path -include *.* -recurse | where 
{($_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).AddHours(-$hours).AddMinutes(-$mins)) -and 
($_.psIsContainer -eq $false)})
    if ($files -ne $NULL)
    {
        for ($idx = 0; $idx -lt $files.Length; $idx++)
        {
            $file = $files[$idx]
            write-host ("Old: " + $file.Name) -Fore Red
        }
    }
}
ShowOldFiles $fullPath $numdays $numhours $nummins
```

Comment: What's your PowerShell version? If you have v3 or newer simply use [`Send-MailMessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-3.0).

Comment: it's version 4Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps:

```
$fullPath = "\\test\avvscan.dat"
$numdays = 2
$numhours = 1
$nummins = 1

function Get-OldFiles($path, $days, $hours, $mins) {
    $refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days).AddHours(-$hours).AddMinutes(-$mins)
    Get-ChildItem $path -Recurse -File | 
        Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -lt $refDate)} |
        ForEach-Object {
            Write-Host ("Old: " + $_.FullName) -ForegroundColor Red
            # emit an object containing the interesting parts for your email
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                'File'          = $_.FullName
                'LastWriteTime' = $_.LastWriteTime
            }
        }
}

$oldFiles = @(Get-OldFiles $fullPath $numdays $numhours $nummins)
if ($oldFiles.Count) {
    # send an email if there are old files found
    $body = $oldFiles | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String
    # look for more options here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-3.0
    Send-MailMessage -From "someone@yourdomain.com" -To "you@yourdomain.com" -SmtpServer "your.smtp.server" -Subject "Old files in $fullPath" -Body $body
}
```